# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\AutoIt\ModenaAutoIt.exe": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While doing the automation of a web application using selenium webdriver, I came across a situation where i need to Upload a file and proceed further.

We are using Java & Tcl scripting language for this.

Below is my TCL code:

```
set methodname "uploadFile"

set action "Open"

set file "C:\\\\BATFiles\\\\InsertUsersAccessGroup.txt"

[$_webdriverObj executeScript $methodname $action $file] --> This calls the java method 'executeScript'
```

Here 'executeScript' is my Java method, coded as below:

```
public void executeScript(String methodName, String action,String file) {

    log.info("Before try block");
    try {
        log.info("Inside try block");
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        log.info("Created a runtime object");
        Process p = r.exec(new String[]{"C:\\AutoIt\\ModenaAutoIt.exe", methodName, action, file });
        log.info("Afte the exec");
        p.waitFor();

    } catch(Exception IOException) {
        log.info("inside exception");
        log.info(IOException);

    }

}
```

Even though the file "ModenaAutoIt.exe" is present in the 'C' directory under 'AutoIt' folder, my script is failing with the Java exception

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\AutoIt\ModenaAutoIt.exe": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory"

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Maybe a permission problem? Did you try to run your code directly (simple main without web-stuff) on that box?

Comment: Tested as below: public static void main(String args[]){
  
  WebHelper wh = new WebHelper();
  wh.executeScript("uploadFile", "Open", "C:\\\\BATFiles\\\\InsertUsersAccessGroup.txt");
 }

Comment: It has given the output like this, even though it actually didn't perform the upload function: (17:16:18,010) WebHelper : INFO  - Before try block
(17:16:18,013) WebHelper : INFO  - Inside try block
(17:16:18,013) WebHelper : INFO  - Created a runtime object
(17:16:18,105) WebHelper : INFO  - Afte the exec

Comment: How would you know if it ran or not? You don't capture the system.out/system.err output of the process. Besides you have your "after the exec" log BEFORE the waitFor() call which is kind of not realistic.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine here, maybe you check with our example call. It also includes the output of the called executable:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ProcBuilderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe", "d:/tmp/tmp.txt");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        final Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader res = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String commandOutput = "";
        String tmp;
        while ((tmp = res.readLine()) != null) {
            commandOutput += tmp;
        }
        System.out.println("output:" + commandOutput);
        if (p.waitFor() != 0) {
            System.out.println("exit value is: " + p.exitValue());
            return;
        }
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception today.

```
 Exception- 
        java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Down.exe"null": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
```

The reason was i was not passing the exact location of the .exe file to the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) method.

Instead of sending below address-->>

```
      String command ="\"C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Resource/Down.exe\"";
```

I was sending-->

```
  String command ="\"C:/Users/Casper/Desktop/Down.exe\"";
```

and because of that was getting the exception.